# Weird ASRock BIOS glitches. Is it possibly a virus from used HDD? Or is it something else?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, virus

I have ASRock Z270 Pro 4 motherboard (Intel).

Got a used HDD drive recently, today plugged it in, and tried to enter <kbd>F11</kbd> Boot selection menu.

Before, it was all ok, but now, it appears glitched (pic 1), until you click enter on single entry, which is there even if nothing is connected to motherboard. I did **not** boot into this new drive (I still don't know what is on it).

I suppose it's a BIOS virus. If it is, please help to remove it. If not, please explain what it is.

I tried: BIOS flash update, CMOS removal - doesn't help

[image]

[image]

Comment: It’s probably not a virus. Why do people think that weird stuff on a computer is always a virus?

Comment: "Got a used HDD drive" - why are you trying to boot from it? Better format it.

Comment: @harrymc I wasn't trying to boot from it, I wanted to format it from USB Win PE.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 because it happened after I connected this HDD to my PC.

Comment: It definitely isn’t a virus

Comment: @Some_Dud - Viruses don’t just modify your UEFI firmware by just plugging them in.

Comment: “because it happened after I connected this HDD to my PC.” There is utterly no way that this is a virus. Just connecting a drive to a PC should not cause the issues you have.

Comment: I hope you didn't pay much for this disk,